Selenium python webdriver : how to remove the message "DevTools listening..."
My setup: Python 3.11
Code looks like:
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("-incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars"); # disabling    infobars
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions"); # disabling     extensions
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu"); # applicable  to  windows os  only
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); # overcome  limited resource problems
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox"); # Bypass  OS security   model
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--headless={headless_option}")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-logging")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-crash-reporter")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-in-process-stack-traces")

service = Service(executable_path=executable_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
url = r'https://www.google.com'
driver.get(url)
driver.quit()

I tried lot of config/options and nothing works.
SO I decided to explore the code and we can see in the file :site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py
self.process = subprocess.Popen(
            cmd,
            env=self.env,
            close_fds=close_file_descriptors,
            stdout=cast(typing.Optional[typing.Union[int, typing.IO[typing.Any]]], self.log_output),
            stderr=cast(typing.Optional[typing.Union[int, typing.IO[typing.Any]]], self.log_output),
            stdin=PIPE,
            creationflags=self.creation_flags,
            startupinfo=start_info,
            **self.popen_kw,
        )

We can understand that it comes from creationflags.
Solutions:
You edit the file of service.py directly but I don't like it because it's not clean.
So I opted for the solution:
#from win32process import CREATE_NO_WINDOW
#CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 134217728
service = Service(executable_path=executable_path,popen_kw={"creation_flags":134217728})

You set the creationflags to CREATE_NO_WINDOW in your script.
You can do it by import or hardcode the value.
Voila !!!
